# Android Intent defaults - detect and clear

Tags: android, android-intent, default

Is there a way to detect that a phone has a default application chosen for an intent such as `android.intent.action.SEND` ?

Is there a way to clear the default application via code?

I'd like to give the user an option to remove the default or at least show a screen telling them how to do it manually, if I can detect it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).  With it, you can determine how an Intent will be handled with resolveActivity(intent).  It looks like the method for clearing the preference (clearPackagePreferredActivities) only works on your own package.

Comment: It looks like you are on the right track, but there is a lot there.  I'll have to research this when I get home.  Thanks.

Comment: Well I was able to detect a lack of a default activity using this method.  Basically I got "com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity" if no default was selected.  So it worked, but I had to do the compare by string, which I am unsure is a promising method given the activity name could change.  Thanks!

Comment: @user432209, I think you can use `resolveActivity(intent, MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)` to avoid the string compare.

Comment: I use 2-step detection of defaults: queryIntentActivities to get all activities for Intent, resolveActivity to get resolved. If resolved one is in the list returned by queryIntentActivities, then there will be no "Complete action using" dialog, thus "default" activity was set.

Comment: @PointerNull this should be a separate answer, because it's the right one.

Answer (score 3):

Use 2-step detection of defaults:

`PackageManager.queryIntentActivities` to get all activities for Intent, `PackageManager.resolveActivity` to get resolved.

If resolved one is in the list returned by `queryIntentActivities`, then there will be no "Complete action using" dialog, thus "default" activity was set.