# Android default activity for Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I stumbled upon this old [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/UkfP70MtjGA) on google groups relating to default activity. Also a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4675405/682869) on SO.

It seems in Android, a user can select a default activity for a particular Intent. However, in my Android 4.3 device, I never see an option for selecting a default activity when the pop up dialog appears for selecting an activity for accomplishing a particular task.

Has the default activity selection feature been removed in 4.3 or a prior version to that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This lines are working for me with the 4.3 OS version.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
```

I guess the problem with you is you might have been selected the Always option in the popup. So it is not working for you.