# Get app that implicit Intent opens

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I'm working with some legacy code and the camera is opened using

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Which is fine. However, some code is running when the camera app is open (I'm not sure entirely why), but it does something if the camera app is in front of the user. The "top" app is retrieved, and then the code that checks if the camera is on top is:

```
 boolean isCameraOnTop = topName.toLowerCase().indexOf("camera") != -1;
```

This was working fine for some time but we've been testing with a new device whose default camera app name is NOT "camera", but something else ("org.codeaurora.snapcam" if you must know). This approach seems flimsy as any device can have any default camera app.

SO, my question is, when I launch the camera app via the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent, how can I find the app that actually gets opened?

Comment: The details in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675405/android-intent-defaults-detect-and-clear) might be useful about using the `PackageManager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I found the solution:

```
activity.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(cameraIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).activityInfo.packageName;
```